# .NET MAUI StaticResource not found for key

Tags: c#, xaml, dependency-injection, maui

When I inject the **mainpage** to the App class constructor I am getting **StaticResource not found for key**    But if I don't inject the Mainpage on the App constructor it works.

I have a global resource Theme file which I call on the **App.xaml.cs** where i declare the static resource:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/LightTheme.xaml" /> <!--Theme file-->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/DarkTheme.xaml" /> <!--Theme file-->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This is my App.cs file:

```
public App(MainPage mainPage)
{

    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = mainPage;

}
```

The following code is in the MainPage.xaml:

```
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource SecondaryBackroundColor}" Grid.Row="0">
        <Image 
            Source="ic_logo.png"
            SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
            HeightRequest="200"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

    </StackLayout>
```

I have added the **MainPage** to the mauiprogram.cs class

`builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();`

Comment: Not sure if it fixes your problem, but it seems that there is a typo in your xaml: you are missing a 'g' in Background. If you dont have that typo in your theme.xaml's it explains your error

Comment: Not a typo i doubled checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a new project to test your code and met the same error. Then I added two break point. One is on the MainPage's construction method and the other is on the App.cs's construction method.

I found that the mainpage's construction method excute before the app.cs' when I used `builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();`. So the error appeared.

Finally, you can follow up this issue about [Can't use App.xaml resources after Dependency Injection .NET MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11485) on the github. Or just use the DynamicResource instead of the StaticResource such as:

```
 <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource SecondaryBackroundColor}"
```

I have tried it. Using the DynamicResource works.

Comment: Using DynamicResource does NOT work. It keeps the Exception away, but the Resource is not resolved.

Comment: No go! This is obviously an error that needs to be solved in MAUI. Don't guide people to use DynamicResource where StaticResource is absolutly the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot inject the "MainPage" into App ctor if MainPage uses static resources from App.xaml (or further references xamls, e.g. Styles.xaml or Colors.xaml). The instance of MainPage is created by DI just before it is injected into App.xaml.cs' constructor. We need to run App.xaml.cs' InitializeComponent() method before we can run MainPage's InitializeComponent() method.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var mainPage = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainPage>();
        this.MainPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage);
    }
}
```

Don't use DynamicResource unless really necessary (e.g. when runtime updates of resources is required).

Answer (score 0):

For this error using .NET 7 I modified my code like this:

```
<!-- In App.xaml -->
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StylesDemo"
              x:Class="StylesDemo.App">
    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>

            <!--APP-level styles-->
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>


            <!--Example of creating Global Styles globalButtonstyle in App.xaml-->
            <Color x:Key="backGroundColorButtonGlobal">#440055</Color>
            <Color x:Key="textColorButtonGlobal">#FFFFFF</Color>

            <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="GlobalButtonstyle">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource textColorButtonGlobal}" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource backGroundColorButtonGlobal}" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Micro" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>



<!-- In MainPage.xaml -->
<Button Text="Global Style" Style="{StaticResource globalButtonStyle}"/>
<Button Text="Global Style" Style="{DynamicResource globalButtonStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what helped as a workaround is to use DI for all pages except the first/main one. That one got new'd in App.xaml.cs.

```
 public partial class App : Application
{
    //public App(MainPage mainPage)
    public App(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainPageViewModel>()));
    }
}
```